# How to put a window on more than one desktop, but not all, in kde

Tags: kde, window-management, workspaces

I am using kde, and have multiple desktops. I can display a window in any desktop, or in all of them. However I would like to display a window in some of them (3 of them).

How do I display a window in more than one, but less than all desktops?

---

using:

- OS: Debian Jessie Gnu/Linux
- Desktop: KDE plasma 5:84

Comment: I suspect that plasma is not one of the few window managers that support this. Does it have a way to run custom code on a desktop change (probably as a plugin of some kind somewhere)?

Comment: You can create a new activity. It will have the same number of desktops, but will not show pinned windows from the default activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using virtual-desktops, use [activities](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/plasma-desktop/plasma-desktop/activities-interface.html). They support this.

(Activities have improved over time, they may not have been good enough in Jessie, but are now)

— Thanks to @meuh for fist comment on this.

Comment: I use both.  Actifities for domain, say: mdeia or dev or personal.  Virtual desktops for context on each activity.  So I have and email desktop for each actvity.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Wayland, and not X11, in order for this to work.

Then assign windows to desktops by means of your choice, e.g. right-click on the title bar > Move to Desktop > ... will be a list of checkboxes where you can select multiple desktops rather than the radiobuttons you get with X11.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for bringing this topic up 9 months later, but your advice definitely doesn't work for Plasma 5.24, which is shipped with Kubuntu 22.04 . Maybe that functionality exists in more recent plasma relases (5.25 or 5.27) - I have no idea.

Comment: In any event it works with the currently supported LTS version, which is Plasma 5.27.